# use mongodb data with mongoose on google map API on node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, google-api

Hello and Welcome to my question!

I want to make a fairly simple website

I have some data in my database and I want to use them on a google maps API
Basically, I want for each place that I have stored, in my db, to have a marker at it's coordinates

My mongoose schema is this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const placeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: String ,
    name: String,
    address: String,
    types:[ String ],
    coordinates:{ lat: Number, lng: Number },
    rating: Number,
    rating_n:Number,
    current_popularity: Number ,
    populartimes:[
        {
            name: String ,
            data: [ Number ]
        }
    ],
    times_spent: [ Number ]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('place', placeSchema)
```

I have read the google API docs and I am trying to do it as they say but I cannot get my data in my js file that my function initMap() is in.

The path is like this:
/login/user

And the user.ejs file is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/user.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="form-uheader">
    <h1>Welcome <%if (typeof user != 'undefined'){%> 
        <%= user.username %> 
        !
    <% } %> </h1>
        <h2>Let's evaluate your choices.</h2>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="openDropdown('map')" class="drop_btn"><img src="images/map.png" alt="#"><h1>What is next to you?</h1></button>
        <button onclick="openDropdown('search')" class="drop_btn"><img src="images/search.png" alt="#"><h1>Points of Interest</h1></button>
        <button onclick="openDropdown('verify')" class="drop_btn"><img src="images/verify.png" alt="#"><h1>Register a Visit</h1></button>
        <button onclick="openDropdown('nervous')" class="drop_btn"><img src="images/nervous.png" alt="#"><h1>Possible contact with a covid case</h1></button>
        <button onclick="openDropdown('patient')" class="drop_btn"><img src="images/patient.png" alt="#"><h1>Do you have Covid?</h1></button>
        <button onclick="openDropdown('edit')" class="drop_btn"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="#"><h1>Edit your profile</h1></button>
    </div>
    <div id = "data">
        <% if(typeof place != 'undefined'){ %> 
            <%var places = place %>
        <% } %> 
    </div>
</div>   

<div class="container">        
    <div id="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-item" id = "item-map">
            <div id="map"></div>
            <% //script for maps API %> 
            <script
              src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAPmkodwFVGpcTcpFyUbeDxaAwYYlUJjnM&callback=initMap&v=weekly"
              async
            ></script>
            <script src="js/map.js"></script>
            <% //END script for maps API %>
            <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-item" id = "item-search">
            <div id = 'search'>
                search
            </div>
            <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-item" id = "item-verify">
            <div id = 'verify'>
                verify
            </div>
            <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-item" id = "item-nervous">
            <div id = 'nervous'>
                nervous
            </div>
            <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-item" id = "item-patient">
            <div id = 'patient'>
                patient
            </div>
            <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-item" id = "item-edit">
            <div id = 'edit'>
                edit
            </div>
            <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically, there are 6 buttons and when 1 of them is pressed a different dropdown menu appears.

I have tried to pass my data to user.ejs, but I could not use my variable between  tags
I cannot connect to mongo schema in static js file (As it was expexted)

Lastly I will present you my login route:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const User = require('../models/user')
const Place = require('../models/place')

// Main Route
router.get('/', (req, res )=> {
    const fromReg = req.query.valid

    console.log(fromReg)
    res.render('login',{
        'page':'login',
        fromReg
    })
})

router.get('/user', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login/user',{
        'page' : 'user'
    })
})

router.get('/admin', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login/admin',{
        'page' : 'admin'
    })
})

//Create About Route
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {

    User.findOne({ email : req.body.email }).then( async (user) => {
        if(user){
            if (user.password === req.body.password) {
                if (user.admin){
                    //login admin
                    res.render('login/admin',{
                        'page' : 'admin',
                        user
                    })
                }else{          
                    const place = await Place.find({})    
                    res.render('login/user',{
                        'page' : 'user',
                        user,
                        place
                    })
                    
                }
            }else{
                const alert = [];
                alert.push({ msg: 'Email or Password is not correct'})
                res.render('login', {
                    'page' : 'login',
                    fromReg : false,
                    alert
                })
            }
        }else{
            const alert = [];
            alert.push({ msg: 'Email or Password is not correct'})
            res.render('login', {
                'page' : 'login',
                fromReg : false,
                alert
            })
        }
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

And I have to tell you that I have 1 javascript file called user.js, that does the animations on the page
and 1 more that is called map.js that basically is copied and pasted from google API documentation

Just to sum up, I would like to know how (but firstly, if) I can use my data in a client-side js file (at least I think this is client-side), or else how can I achieve the end result that I want

Plus this is how my user page looks like:
[image]

Comment: Update: I don't know If I am helping. But I figured out that I can use `res.json()` from my route and then fetch the data like that: 
` fetch("/login/user").then(r => r.json()).then(data => { console.log(data) });`
But I can't understand how to render the login/user and then send data
Plus my fetch does not work. If anyone could help me I would appreciate it